# android Java - Textview not appending text when activity restarts

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, handler, thread-synchronization

I've been trying to create a function in my app that consist in a bluetooth RFID scanner, it's paired to my device and I have it working and all.

I can receive the text and log it in the console, when I compile the activity, everything goes fine, the stick reads the code, and then appends the text into an EditText, but if I go back and enter the activity again, I can see the code in the log, but the text doesn't go to the Edittext.

I tried a lot of different approaches, but nothing seems to work :/

here's the code I have:

```
 /**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bluetooth);


    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    Set<BluetoothDevice> bondedSet = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();


    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enable your BT and re-run this program.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
    if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        if(bondedSet.size() == 1){
            for(BluetoothDevice device : bondedSet){
                address = device.getAddress();
                Log.d("bt:", address);
            }
        }
    }
    String address = "00:A0:96:2A:0A:1B";
    out = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.output);

    BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    Log.d(TAG, device.getName() + " connected");
    myConnection = new ConnectThread(device);
    myConnection.start();

}
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mySocket;
    Message msg;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

        try {
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "CONNECTION IN THREAD DIDNT WORK");
        }
        mySocket = tmp;
    }

    Handler uiThreadHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            out = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.output);
            Object o = msg.obj;
            out.append(o.toString().trim());
            Log.d("handler", o.toString());
        }
    };

    public void run() {
        out = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.output);

        Log.d(TAG, "STARTING TO CONNECT THE SOCKET");
        setName("My Connection Thread");
        InputStream inStream = null;
        boolean run = false;
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
            mySocket.connect();
            run = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, this.getName() + ": CONN DIDNT WORK, Try closing socket");
            try {
                mySocket.close();
                Log.d(TAG, this.getName() + ": CLOSED SOCKET");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                Log.d(TAG, this.getName() + ": COULD CLOSE SOCKET", e1);
                this.destroy();
            }
            run = false;
        }

        synchronized (BluetoothActivity.this) {
            myConnection = null;
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;
        // handle Connection
        try {
            inStream = mySocket.getInputStream();
            while (run) {
                try {
                    bytes = inStream.read(buffer);
                    readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    msg = uiThreadHandler.obtainMessage();
                    msg.obj = readMessage;
                    uiThreadHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Received: " + readMessage);
                } catch (IOException e3) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "disconnected");
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `but if I go back and enter the activity again, I can see the code in the log, but the text doesn't go to the Edittext.`: Do you mean the `handleMessage`, so the `Log.d` part is shown but `.append()` is not?

Comment: that's right.... i'm stuck in that part, since the i can's edit the edittext from the thread directly, i have to use the handleMessage, when i come back, i still see the Log.d showing the message, but not in the edittext, can you help please? i've been trying a lot and nothing fixes the situation.. thanks

Comment: So after you restart your `Activity`, your `Log.d()` line appears. What's the content of that `Object` once restarted your `Activity`?

Comment: the content is what it recieves from the bluetooth stick, once i send data over bluetooth, it show the message on the log console, no on the editText view

Comment: I mean, when you use `Log.d()` on that part that is missfunctioning, do you see the **correct** value once you restart your `Activity`?

Comment: yes, the values are correct, the function is working and i'm recieving the data i wish to show on the screen, the problem here is, the text does not show on the textview..when i first run the app, everythiong works, if i get out of the activity and come back again, it does not show anymore, only on the log console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that this has something to do with the `Thread` itself. When you start your `Activity` for the first time, you also call `.start()` on the `Thread`, that would work fine.

The problem is when you leave your `Activity` and open it up again. In that case, one of `onStop()` or `onPause()` is called (depending on situation), and `onRestart()` or `onResume()` will be called afterwards respectively.

The trick comes now: Meanwhile all that process, your `Thread` is still running. As you show your code, it has not been stopped/paused, and keeps running all the time. So basically my tip is that there's something you do within your `onCreate()` method of your `Activity` that should also be done in your `onPause()` and `onStop()` events, and my *another* tip it's somewhere within your `ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device)` method.

To know how to procceed, I'd firstly define both `onStop()` and `onPause()` methods within your `Activity` and see which is fired, log every attribute to see its value/state, and that way you'll be able to debug what is failing.

[There's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) a diagram of the Activity lifecycle.

Comment: i did create the methods, it goes to onResume, but still, no progress, i think the thread should be stop, and started back again, i have a clean activity and it works fine, but in the activity i need it working the problem persists.

Comment: I'm also of the opinion your thread should be stopped too in the `onPause()` and `onStop()` methods, and be restarted in the `onRestart()` and `onResume()` methods. Have you tested whether it works?

Comment: nop, i use the interrup method and it blows up xD i'm starting to think i shoud buy a farm and start growing potatoes, probably easier....

Comment: Technically is **very** strange that two consecutive lines, without any blocking mechanism such as `synchronized` don't execute secuentially. There must be something strange in there that results in what you're experiencing. Have a detailed look at your code, review all `synchronized` blocks to see whether there could be some that could be blocking your execution. Even if necessary, use the debugger step-by-step tool to see where it's the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved, the code works, and the TextView get the inputstream, the problem was when i left the activity, the thread continued to work, so far, no problem at all, after TONS of hours spent on this, i turn the TextView a static var and it worked :)

If anyone reads this, i hope it helps.